# For-loop to rename documents iteratively

Tags: python, for-loop

For all the `.mcool` files, if the `clr.chromnames` does not start with the `chr` substring, append this substring using `trans = {chrom: f"chr{chrom}" for chrom in clr.chromnames}` followed by `cooler.rename_chroms(clr, trans)`.

My code has redundant nested for-loop. How do I make my code more efficient?

```
for chrom in (chrom for chrom in clr.chromnames if not chrom.startswith("chr")):
    trans = {chrom: f"chr{chrom}" for chrom in clr.chromnames}
```

Full code:

```
pathlist = Path(data_dir).glob('**/*.mcool')
for path in pathlist:
    
     cool_file = str(path)
     filename = cool_file.split("/",1)[1]    
     resolution = [i.rsplit("/", 1)[1] for i in cooler.fileops.list_coolers(cool_file)]
         
     ### load a cooler for each resolution 
     for j in resolution:
            clr = cooler.Cooler(f'{cool_file}::resolutions/{j}')
            for chrom in (chrom for chrom in clr.chromnames if not chrom.startswith("chr")):
                trans = {chrom: f"chr{chrom}" for chrom in clr.chromnames}
                cooler.rename_chroms(clr, trans)
            print(f'chromosomes: {clr.chromnames}, binsize: {clr.binsize}')
```

Input Data:

`clr.chromnames`

['M', 'chr1', '2', '3', 'chr4']
['7', '8', 'chr9', '10', '11', 'chr12']
['X', 'chrY', 'chr1', '2', '4']

Expected output:

`clr.chromnames`

['chrM', 'chr1', 'chr2', 'chr3', 'chr4']
['chr7', 'chr8', 'chr9', 'chr10', 'chr11', 'chr12']
['chrX', 'chrY', 'chr1', 'chr2', 'chr4']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the comprehension down to the statement where you need it.

```
     ### load a cooler for each resolution 
     for j in resolution:
            clr = cooler.Cooler(f'{cool_file}::resolutions/{j}')
            trans = {chrom: f"chr{chrom}" for chrom in clr.chromnames if not chrom.startswith("chr")}
            cooler.rename_chroms(clr, trans)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with cooler, but am speaking in term of Python. Consider this block of code:

```py
for chrom in (chrom for chrom in clr.chromnames if not chrom.startswith("chr")):
    trans = {chrom: f"chr{chrom}" for chrom in clr.chromnames}
    cooler.rename_chroms(clr, trans)
```

I believe that the `cooler.rename_chroms` will rename all, so you don't need to place it into a loop. You can also reduce the two loops into 1:

```py
trans = {
    chrom: f"chr{chrom}"
    for chrom in clr.chromnames
    if not chrom.startswith("chr")
}
cooler.rename_chroms(clr, trans) # Only call once
```

Also, consider this line:

```py
filename = cool_file.split("/",1)[1]
```

If you just want the file name, then this is more robust:

```py
filename = path.name
```

Another one:

```py
clr = cooler.Cooler(f'{cool_file}::resolutions/{j}')
```

Can be:

```py
clr = cooler.Cooler(f"{path}::resolution/{j}")
```

In short, once you work with `pathlib.Path`, you rarely need a reason to convert from `pathlib.Path` to `str`.